# permissionOverwrites syntaxError: Unexpected identifier Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm making a Discord.js ticket bot, and I keep getting stuck at the permissionOverwrites part, it keeps saying that "permissionOverwrites" is an unexpected identifier, even though I followed Discordjs.org.
My code is:

```
  if (reaction.message.id == ticketid && reaction.emoji.name == ``) {
    reaction.users.remove(user);

    reaction.message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${user.username}`, {
      type: 'text'
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: user.id,
          allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
        {
          id: reaction.message.guild.roles.everyone
          deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },

      ],
    }).then(async channel => {
      channel.send(`<@${user.id}>`, new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Ticket`)
      .setDescription(`We will be with you shortly! Use p?close to close this ticket!`)
      .setColor(`#00ff00`) 
      )
    })
  }
```

I'm relatively a beginner at JS and Discord.js, and any help would be appreciated, thanks!

The error I get is

```
/home/runner/ticket-bot/index.js:65
      permissionOverwrites: [
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: can you share with us the error that you get?

Comment: You are missing a `,` after `type: 'text'`

Comment: That worked, but now it says deny is an unexpected identifier

Comment: okay nvm i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the comma after type.

```js
type: 'text',
permissionOverwrites: [
```